# Parameter: 'xxx' is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following prototype:

```
Object.prototype.find = function (path, obj = null) {
    let previous = null;
    obj = !obj ? this : obj;
    for (let i = 0, p = path.split(/[\[\]\.]/), len = p.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (p[i] == '') { continue; }
        let item = p[i];
        obj = obj[item];
        previous = obj;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

I am then calling it like this:

```
let data = [
    {
        id: 1    
    },
    {
        id: 2
    }
];

console.log(data.find('[0].id')) // Error refers to this line
// The result should return 1
```

I am then getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: xxx is not a function

Why is it giving me this error?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/tufuqoz/1/edit?js,console — I can't reproduce the problem (since it says `xxx` is not a function, this probably has something to do with what you use `path` for inside the function … which you haven't shared with us);

Comment: It isn't even executing the function, I will update. One sec...

Comment: no, it was from an ajax request response. I updated it to simplify it though.

Comment: PLEASE do not add things to `Object.prototype`. It is extremely bad form to mutate globals in wants that aren't specifically polyfilling a specification. Also, arrays already _have_ a `.find` that does something else, as of ES6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling `find` on an array. That means you are hitting [the native array find method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (because it is further down the prototype chain than the `find` method you defined on the `Object` prototype).

The array find method expects the first argument to be a function.

If you want to call your `find` method then you need to either do so explicitly:

```
Object.prototype.find("xxx", data); // or
Object.prototype.find.call(data, "xxx");
```

… or give it a name that isn't masked by the existing method on Array.prototype.

(This is a good example of why extending the prototypes of native objects is a bad idea)

Comment: And since you're explicitly referencing it, there is no reason to add it to the prototype in the first place.